# How to set `bbox_to_anchor`'s first two parameters as the upper left coordinate?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In `matplotlib`, I want to plot a legend, and put the legend below the figure. So I write codes like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 7), dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, position=[0.1, 0.28, 0.8, 0.65])
labels = []
for i in range(20):
    ax.plot(data[i, :])
    labels.append(str(i))
ax.legend(labels, ncol=10, loc="lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.15), prop={"size":6}) 
plt.show()
```

It works well. But, actually I'm not sure **what height the legend is**, for example, if I change `ncol=5` or `ncol=2`, the legend's top and the figure's bottom would be overlapped. In my opinion, this situation appears because the first two parameters of `bbox_to_anchor` are the lower left corner coordinates of the bounding box. Of course changing `bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1)` to set legend above would also be a solution, but in my opinion the best solution may be setting `bbox_to_anchor`'s parameters as the upper left corner coordinates, and letting the bbox go down from up.

So my question is, is there a way to make `bbox_to_anchor`'s origin upper but not lower?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `loc="upper center"` in the `ax.legend` call. When `loc` and `bbox_to_anchor` are both used, `loc` specifies which part of the legend box should be put at the position given by `bbox_to_anchor`.